# Headphone jack apparently not working Acer Laptop

Tags: acer-aspire, headphones, earbuds

I can’t hear out of the left speaker of any headphones/earbuds unless I push down the jack connected to the computer. The mixer doesn’t work for the left ear too unless I hold the jack down.